# Keras ImageDataGenerator wrong mapping

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I would like use an ImageDatagenerator from Keras.

My Code:

```
image_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator()
mask_datagen  = image.ImageDataGenerator()
image_datagen.fit(X_train[:int(X_train.shape[0]*validation_split)],seed=42)
mask_datagen.fit(Y_train[:int(Y_train.shape[0]*validation_split)],seed=42)
x=image_datagen.flow(X_train[:int(X_train.shape[0]*validation_split)], batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,shuffle=True)
y=mask_datagen.flow(Y_train[:int(Y_train.shape[0]*validation_split)], batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,shuffle=True)
train_generator = zip(x, y)
return train_generator
```

So, my images are grayscale and my label are binary images. But if I plot the x and y data, it becomes a different label for the original image. There is a mapping error. But where? If I plot my `X_train[0]` and `Y_train[0]` everything is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are shuffling the data with `shuffle=True` in the flow function calls. Because you are using two separate generators, `x` and `y` are getting shuffled independently. To fix this, I believe you need to add `seed=something` to your `.flow` calls.

Also, you shouldn't need to call `.fit` at all, since you aren't using any transformations that are data-dependent.